# How can I configure an Azure VM to securely host Mongo for connection to a web role

Tags: azure, mongodb

I would like to run Mongo DB in Azure. I looked into the hosted version, but the price is high, so I'd like to run my own MongoDB for use with an Azure Web Role. I would like the Mongo DB to remain behind a firewall and not have the ports be available publicly. I would also like all the traffic to stay in the same data center to make access fast and keep down egress charges. Do we have to use some type of VPN connection between servers within the same data center or is there a better way to configure the network connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just need to deploy your cloud service to the same virtual network as your virtual machine running MongoDB. That way both services will be able to communicate directly with each other. The virtual network should be created before the VM and the Cloud Service. During VM creation, just select the virtual network. On your cloud service configuration make sure to add these lines:

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
    <VirtualNetworkSite name="YourVirtualNetworkName" />
    <AddressAssignments>
        <InstanceAddress roleName="YourRoleName">
            <Subnets>
                <Subnet name="YourConfiguredSubnet" />
            </Subnets>
        </InstanceAddress>
    </AddressAssignments>
</NetworkConfiguration>
```

Here's a guide explaning how to create a virtual network

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/create-virtual-network/

Comment: Thanks Bnlf. That makes sense. I also found some help with this link: http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/06/02/connecting-cloud-services-with-virtual-machines-in-windows-azure/#comment-132579